# tidyr::gather produces data.frames with duplicate column names

Tags: r, tidyr

Why does the following code produce a data.frame containing duplicate column names? I would expect it only to contain the newly created c variable.

```
library(tidyr)
testdata <- data.frame(a=1:10, b=21:30, c="test")
testresult <- gather(testdata, c, wert, a, b)
print(colnames(testresult))

# Output R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15), tidyr version 0.7.2:
# "c"    "c"    "wert"
```

Comment: I don't think this happens in more current versions of **tidyr** (current version is 0.8.3).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update the version of your package

```
require(devtools)
install_version("tidyr", version = "0.8.1", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")
```